# How to create a type that refer to a type of an interface's field?

Tags: typescript

How to create a type that refer to a type of an interface's fields?

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
interface SomeOption {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly value: number;
}

type OptionName = typeof SomeOption.name; // <-- this doesn't work of course

const name: OptionName = 'foo'; // ok
const name: OptionName = 5; // error
```

I assume that `SomeOption` might be changed in the future, so I want to say that my variables should be the same type as `SomeOption.name`, not just `string`.

But I wonder how to do that.
Thanks

Comment: (typeof SomeOption)['name']

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine In this case I have `TS2693:  'SomeOption' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another simple syntax:

```
type OptionName = SomeOption['name'];
```